# Installing PlaidML Keras

Tags: python, keras

I am trying to install PlaidML and am following the instructions on the Github. Essentially I am getting the same area as the user here:

[How to install plaidML / plaidML-keras](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56973032/how-to-install-plaidml-plaidml-keras)

I followed the instructions from the developer who responded to that question but still plaidml-setup does not work.

I created a conda environment, and installed PlaidML with pip3. The path is

```
/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages (0.6.4).
```

The error running plaidml-setup is:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/bin/plaidml-setup", line 6, in <module>
from plaidml.plaidml_setup import main

  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/plaidml/__init__.py", line 50, in <module>
import plaidml.settings

  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/plaidml/settings.py", line 33, in <module>
_setup_config('PLAIDML_EXPERIMENTAL_CONFIG', 'experimental.json')

  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/plaidml/settings.py", line 30, in _setup_config
    'Could not find PlaidML configuration file: "{}".'.format(filename))

plaidml.exceptions.PlaidMLError: Could not find PlaidML configuration file: "experimental.json".
```

Following the developers instructions, I navigatated from my virtual environment to the below, and found the following files.

```
(tensorflow) ➜  ~ cd /usr/local/share/plaidml                                               
(tensorflow) ➜  plaidml 
(tensorflow) ➜  plaidml ls
config.json          experimental.json    plaidml-config.cmake
```

Answer (score 0):

I simply forgot to do pip3 install keras followed by pip3 install tensorflow after creating my virtual environment.