# Keras and PlaidML errors appear despite successful setup

Tags: python, keras, gpgpu, plaidml

I have the up-to-date versions of Keras and PlaidML installed. I ran the file plaidml-setup and configured plaidml to use my AMD GPU:

```
C:\WinPython\python-3.6.1.amd64\Scripts>plaidml-setup

PlaidML Setup (0.7.0)

(...)


Default Config Devices:
   llvm_cpu.0 : CPU (via LLVM)

Experimental Config Devices:
   llvm_cpu.0 : CPU (via LLVM)
   opencl_amd_gfx902.0 : Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. gfx902 (OpenCL)

Using experimental devices can cause poor performance, crashes, and other nastiness.

Enable experimental device support? (y,n)[n]:y

Multiple devices detected (You can override by setting PLAIDML_DEVICE_IDS).
Please choose a default device:

   1 : llvm_cpu.0
   2 : opencl_amd_gfx902.0

Default device? (1,2)[1]:2

Selected device:
    opencl_amd_gfx902.0

Almost done. Multiplying some matrices...
Tile code:
  function (B[X,Z], C[Z,Y]) -> (A) { A[x,y : X,Y] = +(B[x,z] * C[z,y]); }
Whew. That worked.

Save settings to C:\Users\jsupi\.plaidml? (y,n)[y]:y
Success!
```

I succesfully tested the installation by running `plaidbench keras mobilenet`:

```
C:\WinPython\python-3.6.1.amd64\Scripts>plaidbench keras mobilenet
Running 1024 examples with mobilenet, batch size 1, on backend plaid
INFO:plaidml:Opening device "opencl_amd_gfx902.0"
Compiling network... Warming up... Running...
Example finished, elapsed: 7.484s (compile), 26.724s (execution)

-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Network Name         Inference Latency         Time / FPS
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
mobilenet            26.10 ms                  11.90 ms / 84.02 fps
Correctness: PASS, max_error: 1.8053706298815086e-05, max_abs_error: 9.760260581970215e-07, fail_ratio: 0.0
```

Then I wanted to run some python module on my GPU. I read in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56973032/how-to-install-plaidml-plaidml-keras) that I need to set `os.environ["RUNFILES_DIR"]` and `os.environ["PLAIDML_NATIVE_PATH"]` to correct paths, for example:

```
os.environ["RUNFILES_DIR"] = "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/share/plaidml"
os.environ["PLAIDML_NATIVE_PATH"] = "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/libplaidml.dylib"
```

The problem is that I can't find anything resembling the last one in my system. I ran the Windows search function, but it couldn't find the `libplaidml.dylib` file anywhere. So I tried the following:

```
import os
os.environ["KERAS_BACKEND"] = "plaidml.keras.backend"
os.environ["RUNFILES_DIR"] = "C://Users/jsupi/.plaidml"
#os.environ["PLAIDML_NATIVE_PATH"] = "C:/Windows/WinPython/python-3.6.1.amd64/Lib/site-packages"
import numpy as np
import tensorflow as tf
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import keras


from keras.datasets import mnist #to import our dataset
from keras.models import Sequential, Model # imports our type of network
from keras.layers import Dense, Flatten, Input # imports our layers we want to use

from keras.losses import categorical_crossentropy #loss function
from keras.optimizers import Adam, SGD #optimisers
from keras.utils import to_categorical #some function for data preparation


batch_size = 128
num_classes = 10
epochs = 50

# input image dimensions
img_rows, img_cols = 28, 28

# the data, split between train and test sets
(x_train, y_train), (x_test, y_test) = mnist.load_data()


x_train = x_train.astype('float32')
x_test = x_test.astype('float32')
x_train /= 255
x_test /= 255
print('x_train shape:', x_train.shape)
print(x_train.shape[0], 'train samples')
print(x_test.shape[0], 'test samples')

# convert class vectors to binary class matrices
y_train = to_categorical(y_train, num_classes)
y_test = to_categorical(y_test, num_classes)



#Neural network with single dense hidden layer

model = Sequential()
#model.add(Input(input_shape=(28,28)))
model.add(Flatten(input_shape=(28,28)))
model.add(Dense(128, activation='relu'))
model.add(Dense(num_classes, activation='softmax'))
```

and got the error message:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:\Kuba\Machine Learning\DigitRecognitionKeras.py", line 51, in <module>
    model.add(Dense(128, activation='relu'))
  File "C:\WinPython\python-3.6.1.amd64\lib\site-packages\keras\engine\sequential.py", line 181, in add
    output_tensor = layer(self.outputs[0])
  File "C:\WinPython\python-3.6.1.amd64\lib\site-packages\keras\engine\base_layer.py", line 431, in __call__
    self.build(unpack_singleton(input_shapes))
  File "C:\WinPython\python-3.6.1.amd64\lib\site-packages\keras\layers\core.py", line 866, in build
    constraint=self.kernel_constraint)
  File "C:\WinPython\python-3.6.1.amd64\lib\site-packages\keras\legacy\interfaces.py", line 91, in wrapper
    return func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\WinPython\python-3.6.1.amd64\lib\site-packages\keras\engine\base_layer.py", line 249, in add_weight
    weight = K.variable(initializer(shape),
  File "C:\WinPython\python-3.6.1.amd64\lib\site-packages\keras\initializers.py", line 218, in __call__
    dtype=dtype, seed=self.seed)
  File "C:\WinPython\python-3.6.1.amd64\lib\site-packages\plaidml\keras\backend.py", line 59, in wrapper
    return func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\WinPython\python-3.6.1.amd64\lib\site-packages\plaidml\keras\backend.py", line 1305, in random_uniform
    rng_state = _make_rng_state(seed)
  File "C:\WinPython\python-3.6.1.amd64\lib\site-packages\plaidml\keras\backend.py", line 205, in _make_rng_state
    rng_state = variable(rng_init, dtype='uint32')
  File "C:\WinPython\python-3.6.1.amd64\lib\site-packages\plaidml\keras\backend.py", line 59, in wrapper
    return func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\WinPython\python-3.6.1.amd64\lib\site-packages\plaidml\keras\backend.py", line 1935, in variable
    _device(), plaidml.Shape(_ctx, ptile.convert_np_dtype_to_pml(dtype), *value.shape))
  File "C:\WinPython\python-3.6.1.amd64\lib\site-packages\plaidml\keras\backend.py", line 102, in _device
    devices = plaidml.devices(_ctx)
  File "C:\WinPython\python-3.6.1.amd64\lib\site-packages\plaidml\__init__.py", line 1075, in devices
    plaidml.settings.start_session()
  File "C:\WinPython\python-3.6.1.amd64\lib\site-packages\plaidml\settings.py", line 77, in start_session
    raise plaidml.exceptions.PlaidMLError('PlaidML is not configured. Run plaidml-setup.')
plaidml.exceptions.PlaidMLError: PlaidML is not configured. Run plaidml-setup.
```

Note the last line, which says that PlaidML is not configured even though I have just done that and succesfully tested it. The program runs fine if I comment out the first 3 lines (thus running it without plaidml) and write tensorflow.keras instead of keras in all the "import" lines (it seems to be necessary without plaidml).

Do you have any ideas how to resolve this issue? I have Windows 10 and Python 3.6.

UPDATE 08/11/2021:
I have recently solved the problem after a suggestion made by a friend. First of all, 'libplaidml.dylib' is a Linux library file, and I have Windows, so I had to set the path to an analogous .dll file instead (I also use r"" to make sure there are no problems with backslashes):

```
os.environ["KERAS_BACKEND"] = "plaidml.keras.backend"
os.environ["RUNFILES_DIR"] = r"C:\\Users\jsupi\.plaidml"
os.environ["PLAIDML_NATIVE_PATH"] = r"C:\\WinPython\python-3.6.1.amd64\Library\bin\plaidml.dll"
```

That done, I also created a virtual environment with all the necessary python libraries installed (but that's probably not necessary) and I ran the python script from the command line rather than from the GUI.

I hope I didn't forget to write any essential step here. Oh, and one thing that confused me - after the fixes described above - was how little of my GPU was used during some computations. When I switched plaidml back to using the CPU, the runtime of a script increased 100-fold, and only that did convince me the GPU had been working after all.

Answer (score 0):

I am also working with plaidml started recently.
I took your code and commented one import statement

```
import os
os.environ["KERAS_BACKEND"] = "plaidml.keras.backend"
os.environ["RUNFILES_DIR"] = "C://Users/jsupi/.plaidml"
#os.environ["PLAIDML_NATIVE_PATH"] = "C:/Windows/WinPython/python-3.6.1.amd64/Lib/site-packages"
import numpy as np
#import tensorflow as tf <- commented this line, as I did not install tensorflow
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import keras


from keras.datasets import mnist #to import our dataset
from keras.models import Sequential, Model # imports our type of network
from keras.layers import Dense, Flatten, Input # imports our layers we want to use

from keras.losses import categorical_crossentropy #loss function
from keras.optimizers import Adam, SGD #optimisers
from keras.utils import to_categorical #some function for data preparation


batch_size = 128
num_classes = 10
epochs = 50

# input image dimensions
img_rows, img_cols = 28, 28

# the data, split between train and test sets
(x_train, y_train), (x_test, y_test) = mnist.load_data()


x_train = x_train.astype('float32')
x_test = x_test.astype('float32')
x_train /= 255
x_test /= 255
print('x_train shape:', x_train.shape)
print(x_train.shape[0], 'train samples')
print(x_test.shape[0], 'test samples')

# convert class vectors to binary class matrices
y_train = to_categorical(y_train, num_classes)
y_test = to_categorical(y_test, num_classes)



#Neural network with single dense hidden layer

model = Sequential()
#model.add(Input(input_shape=(28,28)))
model.add(Flatten(input_shape=(28,28)))
model.add(Dense(128, activation='relu'))
model.add(Dense(num_classes, activation='softmax'))
```

It worked and printed the output

```
Using plaidml.keras.backend backend.
x_train shape: (60000, 28, 28)
60000 train samples
10000 test samples
INFO:plaidml:Opening device "opencl_amd_ellesmere.0"
```

May be your plaidml may not be setup properly.
set the environment variable for verbose log as `export PLAIDML_VERBOSE=1`. This will print out if there is any error while running plailml-setup.
I did not install tensorflow framework and only using plaidml, keras. Though, I see some installation guide plaidml with tensorflow.
I am running with ubuntu 20.04